Limiting the scope of an authorized user in an SSH principals file using a FQDN
I've been using the SSH AuthorizedPrincipalsFile feature on Linux for quite some time and it works fine, but I've discovered recently that it is possible to limit the provenance of a user using the "from=" keyword in the principals file.
However, the problem is that as soon as I add that keyword with an FQDN matching the one used as principals when signing the host key of the source, I cannot login anymore. For instance:

local signed host key:
ssh_host_ed25519_key-cert.pub:
        Type: ...
        Public key: ...
        Signing CA: ...
        Key ID: "hostname.example.com"
        Serial: 0
        Valid: from 2024-05-02T17:06:00 to 2025-05-01T17:07:48
        Principals: 
                hostname.example.com


local signed user key:
id_ed25519-cert.pub:
        Type: ...
        Public key: ...
        Signing CA: ...
        Key ID: "hostname.example.com"
        Serial: 0
        Valid: from 2024-05-02T17:18:00 to 2025-05-01T17:19:47
        Principals: 
                user


on the remote host user_principals:
from="hostname.example.com" user


on the remote host /etc/hosts:
<ipv6_address> hostname.example.com




If I ssh as user from the local host hostname.example.com into the remote host, it fails.
If I remove the from="hostname.example.com" keyword from the remote principals file, the login succeeds.
If I replace the from="hostname.example.com" keyword by from="*.example.com", the login fails.
If I replace the from="hostname.example.com" keyword by from="<ipv6_address>"  where <ipv6_address> is the actual local hostname ipv6 address, the login succeeds.


how does the SSH server theoretically verify the source:


using the principals of the source host certificate?
using the "Key ID" of the user certificate?
making a reverse DNS lookup using the source IP address?


Has anyone been actually able to implement this with a from="FQDN" or is this an SSH server bug?

Environment:

local host:

Ubuntu noble
openssh-client: 1:9.6p1-3ubuntu13


remote host:

Ubuntu lunar
openssh-server: 1:9.0p1-1ubuntu8.7



